# Selenium - Find children containing classes

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I cannot find any regular expression to make it work.

**What I need to archive**

In a herarchy, I would like to get all the children (including several levels) that contains some specific classes.

For example: I would like the WebElements with classes "black" or "white"

```
<div class="initial-div">
  <div class="red">
     <div class="white">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="black">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

It should be able to find both the "Hello" and "Goodbye" divs, as they are both children.

**My approach**

I am trying to do it using Selenium and searching by the xPath. My expression looks like:

```
List<WebElement> nodes = initialNode.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='black' or @class='white']"));
```

But I am getting all the time "Invalid Expression exceptions" or no results.

Could someone give me a hand with this?

Thank you in advance!

**SOLVED!**

It was more complicated that I though, but I finally make it. I share with you, in case that someone is searching for this at any time:

```
List<WebElement> nodes = initialNode.findElements(By.xpath("*//descendant::div[contains(@class, 'black') or contains(@class, 'white)]"));
```

Comment: Try:`//div[@class='white']|//div[@class='black']`

Comment: Hello, that did not work, but I finally make it work!
I am updating the main post.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<WebElement> nodes = initialNode.findElements(By.xpath("*//descendant::div[contains(@class, 'black') or contains(@class, 'white)]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element has two xpath, then you can write two xpaths like below:

`xpath1 | xpath2`

Eg:

```
//div[@class="black"] | //div[@class=“white"]
```

It will choose any one xpath